# Regex Problem: name capture, preg_match

Tags: regex, preg-match

Given the following strings:

```
application/pdf; name=a.pdf
application/pdf; name="b.pdf"
application/pdf; name="c.pdf
application/pdf; name=d.pdf"
```

I need the following values in a capture named "filename":

```
a.pdf
b.pdf
c.pdf
d.pdf
```

The following regex works for `a.pdf`, but fails for the rest due to the double quotes:

```
name=(?<filename>.*)
```

Any suggestions how I can get the rest? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
/name="?(?<filename>[^"]*)"?/
```

Comment: Note that this would match `application/pdf; name=b.pdf"` - ie imbalanced quoting, but it think it's OK

Comment: The 4th example is like that, so I though it would be interesting to match is as well

Comment: Doesn't work. It matched: `a.pdf` and `application/pdf; name=` and `c.pdf` and `application/pdf; name=d.pdf`

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: are you passing any flag to ignore newlines? I'm not sure on how the PHP regex work. Try appending a `$`.